# One of my MySQL query works, while the other modified case doesn't work. Anything I'm missing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['mac']) && isset($_POST['hours']))        
    {           
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("Select * from ".$database.".`startstopdata` where Emp_name='".$name."' AND (date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."') AND (Location!= Stop_location OR MacAddress != Stop_mac) AND days=0 AND hours<8;");       
    }
else if(isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['mac']) && isset($_POST['hours']) && !isset($_POST['name']))      
    {           
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("Select * from ".$database.".`startstopdata` where (date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."') AND (Location!= Stop_location AND MacAddress != Stop_mac) AND (days=0 AND hours<8);");         
    }
```

There are multiple queries similar to this. The ones including `$name` works while the one which do not require `$name` doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: assuming that `$name` is created from `$_POST['name']`, as long as the other variables, *both* queries are vulnerable to SQL-injection. be on the safe side and use parameterized statements.

Comment: Yes, `$name` is created from `$_POST['name']` and I'm aware of SQL Injection vulnerability. Thanks for reminder, I'll bind the parameters in the next stage. But that does not answers my question, does it?

Comment: no it doesn't. that's why it's a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: print $_POST inside the else if construct and see if any of these values in coming as null , the only difference that I can see in the above two queries is that brackets are added in  days=0 AND hours<8 set of condition in the later one

Comment: There is difference of `NOT` operator inside `if` in its last condition `!isset($_POST['name'])` in second case, i.e, when the user has not filled that field.

Comment: @yankianki any suggestions?

Comment: if $_POST['name'] is not set only then it will go in the second condition since its 'else if', so you do not have to again check if !isset($_POST['name'] in the that

Comment: I tested it and it was unset, but still the query doesn't executes @yankianki

Comment: can you print the error trace its throwing

Comment: It is not throwing any error. The page simply reloads and nothing happens.@yankianki